# Fade in Function Won't Work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am very new to jQuery, so please bear with me. I'm trying to make a div whose class is called "cover" fade in using its opacity CSS attribute. Here's the jQuery:

```
var div = $('.cover');
var divH = div.height();
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  var st = $(this).scrollTop();
  div.css({ 'opacity' : (0 + st/divH) });
});
```

I have a JSFiddle with the CSS and HTML bits here: http://jsfiddle.net/ShubhangD/6xm0o8ta/. This seems like a simple thing to do, but it's not working at all. Can anyone please help me out?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: You haven't linked in jQuery in your fiddle.  Works fine here:  http://jsfiddle.net/4guh41af/

Comment: Please include all relevant code in your post and **don't** just include a link to a code hosting site. Your post should stand alone from any other resource; consider what would happen if that site went down in the future!

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. It's not working in my actual code. I have that exact jQuery right before the closing body tag. Do you know what could be wrong?

Comment: Is jQuery working on the rest of your page? If not, maybe your script tag is messed up. What code are you using to get the jQuery?

Comment: That's the only bit of jQuery on the entire page. Like I said, I'm very new to this; what do you mean by the link being messed up?

Comment: On your actual HTML page (not the JSFiddle), do you have something similar to `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` in your code?

Comment: Oh wow, no I didn't. Trust me, I am embarrassed. Thanks so much for the help! :)

Comment: Great, I'm glad it works. I've posted it as an answer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing this script tag in your code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>‌​
```